# Node.js - Return res.status VS res.status

Tags: node.js, http, express, response

I am curious about the difference of returning a response and just creating a response.

I have seen a vast amount of code examples using both `return res.status(xxx).json(x)` and `res.status(xxx).json(x)`.

Is anyone able to elaborate on the difference between the two?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

If you have a condition and you want to exit early you would use return because calling res.send() more than once will throw an error. For example:

```
//...Fetch a post from db

if(!post){
  // Will return response and not run the rest of the code after next line
  return res.status(404).send({message: "Could not find post."})
}

//...Do some work (ie. update post)

// Return response
res.status(200).send({message: "Updated post successfuly"})
```

Answer (score 11):

As explained by @kasho, this is only necessary for short-circuiting the function. However, I would not recommend to return the `send()` call itself, but rather after it. Otherwise it gives the wrong expression, that the return value of the `send()` call was important, which it isn't, as it is only `undefined`.

```js
if (!isAuthenticated) {
  res.sendStatus(401)
  return
}

res
  .status(200)
  .send(user)
```

Answer (score 0):

The return statement will terminate the function and not go any further. For example, if you have a middleware function that `return res.status(xxx).json(x)`, the next function (middleware or final handler) will stop executing since a response has already been return. However, if you did not return the response, it will continue executing the next function in the sequence.